# Error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector

Tags: c

When I compile the following C code with Clang, I get this error:  "Error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector"  at the line collect[i][j] = result.

```
double * Matrix_Add(double *X, double *Y, double *input_length)
{
    int rows = (int)input_length[0];
    int cols = (int)input_length[1];
    int output_size = rows * cols;

    double *collect = (double *)calloc(rows * cols, sizeof(double));
    double result; 

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    // __________

    while (i <= rows){ 
        j = 1;
        while (j <= cols){

            result = X[i] + Y[j];
            collect[i][j] = result;
            j = j + 1; }

        i = i + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So I added a int*

```
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int * i_ptr =  &i;
    int * j_ptr =  &j;

    // __________

    while (i <= rows){ 
    j = 1;
    while (j <= cols){

        result = X[i] + Y[j];
        collect[i_ptr][j_ptr] = result;
        //collect[i][j] = result;
        j = j + 1; }

    i = i + 1;
}
```

but when I compile, I get "error: array subscript is not an integer."

I've read about a dozen Stack Overflow posts on this and I still don't know how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: `collect` is a pointer to a "one-dimensional" array - you are trying to use it like a "two-dimensional" array

Comment: And I have no idea what you did in that second example, but randomly guessing definitely does not work in C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `collect` is declared as a `double *`, it follows that `collect[i]` is a `double`.  You cannot subscript that.

Perhaps you want `collect[i * cols + j]` instead.

Or if your compiler supports the variable-length array option, then perhaps you wanted to declare `collect` differently:

```
double (*collect)[cols] = calloc(rows * sizeof(*collect));
```

..., in which case `collect[i][j]` would do what you expect.